# Как получить упомянутого человека в discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

у меня есть строка:`for user1 in cursor.execute("SELECT nickname,sId,elo,kills,deaths,wins,lose FROM users WHERE login = ?",[ctx.mention.id]):`
и мне нужно получить id именно ПЕРВОГО упомянутого человека т.к в будущем мне надо будет управлять еще 10 пользователями

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При создании команды Вы можете указать аргумент в который будет помещен пользователь:

```
async def test(ctx, user: discord.Member) #user - туда будем помещён упомянутый пользователь.
```

Теперь просто вставляем его `ID`:

```
for user1 in cursor.execute("SELECT nickname,sId,elo,kills,deaths,wins,lose FROM users WHERE login = ?",(user.id)):
```

Полный код:

```
async def test(ctx, user: discord.Member)
    for user1 in cursor.execute("SELECT nickname,sId,elo,kills,deaths,wins,lose FROM users WHERE login = ?",(user.id)):
        name = user1[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете получить ID первого упомянутого человека, используя функцию ctx.mentions[0].id из модуля discord.py. Пример:

```
for user1 in cursor.execute("SELECT nickname,sId,elo,kills,deaths,wins,lose FROM users WHERE login = ?",[ctx.mentions[0].id]):
```